# flutter: crashes --com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}:

Tags: android, flutter

I deployed my Flutter app to the play store and now I am seeing some crashes via crash analytics . I and some help to understand and fix it..here is the crash. information

I am using Firebase_auth plugin and I have this in my grade file

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

---- error ------

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.RandstadRecruiter/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2665(ActivityThread.java:2665)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2726(ActivityThread.java:2726)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1477(ActivityThread.java:1477)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6119(ActivityThread.java:6119)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 886(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 776(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main + 107(XposedBridge.java:107)
```